# Running console application/batch file interactively inside Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

From this post, I see that we can monitor the `cmd` output and show it in Inno setup UI:
[Embedded CMD in Inno Setup installer (show command output on a custom page)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56910906/850848)

In my case , in `Run` section I launch a `bat`, which will do some process based on a user input.

(e.g whether install / modify a package - user will input <kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd> – something like that)

Is it possible to embed an interactive cmd in to Inno Setup GUI? The problem is if user closes the `cmd` prompt in-between then the installation will not be proper and leads to corrupted files.

What is right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably doable – but a lot of work and not user-friendly anyway.

---

I'd use Inno Setup GUI to ask all questions in advance and then run the batch file non-interactively.

- Either by modifying the batch file to accept parameters to control its options.
  See [Inno Setup: How to pass variable from [Code] to [Run] (or other section)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19299669/850848)
- Or, if you cannot modify the batch file, by providing an answer file.
  See [How to provide an input to a batch file ran using Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29195895/850848)